# Change value of selectric drop down programmatically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectric

What is a good way to change the value of a Selectric drop down programmatically based on name? I know the value of the option I want to set as selected. I don't know the name or the index.

Here is my best attempt:

```
$('.store-availability').prop('selectedIndex', 3).selectric('refresh').change();
```

Since I don't know the index I would have to jQuery.Index() on the options first to find it or something like that. Is there a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the value of the option you want to set you can use the setter of `val()`, then call `refresh` on the selectric instance, like this:

```
$('.store-availability').val(yourValueHere).change().selectric('refresh');
```